# Migrate from Boostrap to Google's Material Design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-api, material-design

I have been using Twitter Boostrap for my web apps. Recently, I have started liking Google's Material Design. Is there any way I can replace all the Bootstrap's Look and Feel by Material Design's? I don't wanna change the applied classes to HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't move instantly from `Bootstrap` to `Material.io` without changing 1 by 1 code/syntax on bootstrap. So change it while studying everything you learned on `material.io` and dont be lazy.